# Unity Soomla simple code giving me errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

Here is an Asset class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Soomla.Store;

public class StoreAssets : Soomla.Store.IStoreAssets {

public int GetVersion() {
    return 0;
}

public VirtualCurrency[] GetCurrencies() {
    return new VirtualCurrency[]{MW_ITEM};
}

public VirtualGood[] GetGoods() {
    return new VirtualGood[] {};
}

public VirtualCurrencyPack[] GetCurrencyPacks() {
    return new VirtualCurrencyPack[] {MW_ITEM1,MW_ITEM2,MW_ITEM3};
}

public VirtualCategory[] GetCategories() {
    return new VirtualCategory[]{};
}

public NonConsumableItem[] GetNonConsumableItems() {
    return new NonConsumableItem[]{};
}

public const string ITEMID = "mw_coin";//**NOT GOOGLE PLAY PRODUCT ID**
public const string FIFTY_COINS = "mw1";//**google play store product id**
public const string ONEFIFTY_COINS = "mw2";//**google play store product id**
public const string THREEHUNDRED_COINS = "mw3";//**google play store product id**

public static VirtualCurrency MW_ITEM = new VirtualCurrency ("Coins", "", ITEMID);
public static VirtualCurrencyPack MW_ITEM1 = new VirtualCurrencyPack("Buy 50 Coins", 
                                                                     "Use 50 coins wisely in your game.",
                                                                     "Coins_50",//**NOT GOOGLE PLAY PRODUCT ID**
                                                                     50,
                                                                     ITEMID,
                                                                     new PurchaseWithMarket(FIFTY_COINS,0.99f)
                                                                     );
public static VirtualCurrencyPack MW_ITEM2 = new VirtualCurrencyPack("Buy 150 Coins", 
                                                                     "Use 150 coins wisely in your game.",
                                                                     "Coins_150",//**NOT GOOGLE PLAY PRODUCT ID**
                                                                     150,
                                                                     ITEMID,
                                                                     new PurchaseWithMarket(ONEFIFTY_COINS,1.99f)
                                                                     );
public static VirtualCurrencyPack MW_ITEM3 = new VirtualCurrencyPack("Buy 300 Coins", 
                                                                     "Use 300 coins wisely in your game.",
                                                                     "Coins_300",//**NOT GOOGLE PLAY PRODUCT ID**
                                                                     300,
                                                                     ITEMID,
                                                                     new PurchaseWithMarket(THREEHUNDRED_COINS,2.99f)
                                                                     );

}
```

Soomla has lots of IDS to assign. I am just confused which id to use where.

Here I am getting errors when I am calling buy item MW_ITEM1:

**AndroidJavaException: com.soomla.store.exceptions.VirtualItem NotFoundException: Virtual item was not found when searching with productId=Coin s_50**

I have deleted the app from device and reinstalled, then also not working, same error.
I have deleted the app from device and updated app version and Soomla GetVersion() value build it and installed it using adb, then also it is giving me same error.

I am seeking help guys. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. In my case the problem was that the items were not active in Google Play.

Go to your in-app purchases settings in google play, select the inactive items, and change them to active.